# Is Marcellus a serif font?

Tags: typefaces, serif

I was searching for serif fonts on [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) and happened across [Marcellus](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Marcellus).

[image: A sample of the Marcellus font, with the "Grumpy wizards" sample text]

However, if I were shown it out of any context, I'd call it a sans-serif font. I can see small hits of what might be called serifs, but on most characters it just seems like a tapered-out stroke. **Is Marcellus considered serif, sans-serif, or something else altogether?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Fonts like this are called glyphic serif. But since for example Optima is widely considered a sans serif, I don’t think it would be wrong to say the same for Marcellus.

By the way: The German font classification system (DIN 16518) considers fonts like this to be Antiqua-Variants. Antiqua-fonts that can’t be classified clearly as serif or sans-serif go in this category.

Answer (score 6):

I consider it to be a serif font, the letters have very small serifs but they are there.

Comment: Well, yes, every user of the site could post their personal opinion as to whether it's a serif font or not but that doesn't really achieve much.

Comment: I don't think this is purely an opinion. The glyphs do have measurable serifs, and the definition of sans-serif is that there are NO serifs, not merely small ones.